# How can I call a Function with a href?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I´m trying to call a function into a `href`, my `function` is on `functions.php`
and my `href` is on `views/something.php`

so, this is my function:

```
function discount($connection, $us){
    $discount = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE postule SET seen = 1 WHERE id = $us");
    $discount->execute();
    return $discount;
}
```

and my `link button` is on an `<li>` (not in a form):

```
<?php foreach ($total_notu as $notu) : ?>
    <li><a onClick="<?php discount() ?>" href="notificaciones.php"> Notificaciones <span class="badge "><?php echo "$notu[0]"; ?></span></a></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

(Do not pay attention to the foreach)

Comment: You're unable to call a PHP function directly from HTML. You'll need to either post a form or use ajax. The way you're doing it at the moment it'll call `discount` during each iteration of the loop which will fail because `discount` requires 2 parameters to be passed.

Comment: @sjdaws so, what do you recommend me?

Comment: @jdaws I'dont know if this is safety, and if isn't just let me know but i make my link run the function with `onClick="<?php discount($conexion, $us) ?>"`

Comment: is `$notu[0]` the ID that should be passed here: `discount($conexion, $us)` as  `$us` ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change this to use an ajax call or form post to call the PHP function.

Here's a really basic example which should point you in the right direction

discount.php

```
<?php

    // Load $connection from somewhere

    // Get user, it's better to get this from a cookie or session rather than GET
    $user = $_GET['user']

    $discount = $connection->prepare("UPDATE postule SET seen = 1 WHERE id = :user");
    $discount->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $result = $discount->execute();

    // Throw error if something went wrong with the update, this will cause $.ajax to use the error function
    if (!$result) {
        http_response_code(500);
    }
```

html, assuming `$notu[0]` contains the user id

```
<?php foreach ($total_notu as $notu) : ?>
    <li><a onClick="return callDiscount('<?php echo "$notu[0]"; ?>');" href="#"> Notificaciones <span class="badge "><?php echo "$notu[0]"; ?></span></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

js, requires [jquery](https://code.jquery.com)

```
function callDiscount(user_id)
{
    // Perform ajax call to discount.php
    $.ajax({
        url: '/discount.php?user=' + user_id, 
        error: function() {
            alert('An error occurred');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // Redirect user to notificaciones.php
            document.location = '/notificaciones.php';
        }
    });

    // Prevent link click doing anything
    return false;
}
```